# file MobileCoreServices-3PK2VQ0R2SYLI.pcm missing after latest firebase upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

From time to time, when upgrading Firebase API a warning can occur that a file is missing.  This time around it's `MobileCoreServices-3PK2VQ0R2SYLI.pcm`.  Does anyone know what this file does or how to remove the warning (it's shown below)? `/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/1IO1UHEYA1R6B/MobileCoreServices-3PK2VQ0R2SYLI.pcm: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's caches aren't always reliable, especially after library upgrades or downgrades. It's always a good idea to blow away DerivedData when Xcode starts acting weird:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

At the cost of a few seconds, DerivedData will automatically get updated based on the current state.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I solved it based on another answer you had given to a different question.  I ran {pod deintegrate} and {pod install} and the warning has disappeared.